# Why is 'X x; x();' allowed, when 'X' defines a conversion to function pointer, but not, when it defines a conversion to a functor?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, functor, function-call

```
void f(int){}
typedef void (*f_ptr)(int);

struct Functor{
  void operator()(int){}
};

struct X{
  operator f_ptr(){ return f; }
};

struct Y{
  operator Functor(){ return Functor(); }
};

int main(){
  X x; Y y;
  x(5); // works ?!
  y(5); // doesn't ?!
}
```

[Live example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/jRnWi). Output:

> error: no match for call to '(Y) (int)'

**Q1: Why is the call to `x(5)` allowed, even though `X` only defines a conversion to function pointer, and not `operator()`?**

**Q2: Conversely, why is the same thing not allowed, if we define a conversion to another functor?**

Comment: Something to do with the complicated conversion rules of C++

Comment: @Seth: Who'd have guessed. :P

Comment: I just thought I'd let you guys know :)

Comment: A: must be some crazy corner case. Anyway, it is the best to avoid conversion operators all together

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
x(5); // works ?!
```

This implicitly casts `x` to an `f_ptr` and calls that. C++11 standard:

> #### § 13.3.1.1.2 Call to object of class type [over.call.object]
>
> 2) In addition, for each non-explicit conversion function declared in T of the form
>
> ```
> operator conversion-type-id ( ) attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier ;
> ```
>
> […where `conversion-type-id` denotes the type “pointer to function of `(P1,...,Pn)` returning `R`”…]

---

```
y(5); // doesn't ?!
```

The standard doesn't mention anything about implicit conversion to class types that overload `operator()` (aka functors), which implies that the compiler doesn't allow that.

You must cast it explicitly:

```
static_cast<Functor>(y)(5);
```

Comment: You found the language in the C++ ISO specification that specifically permits the cast to a function pointer but not to a functor.  That's very useful!

Comment: That's... not as arcane as I thought it would be. :) Though, I wonder if this could be considered a language defect...