# How do I determine if a type is callable with only const references?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I want to write a C++ metafunction `is_callable<F, Arg>` that defines `value` to be `true`, if and only if the type F has the function call operator of the form `SomeReturnType operator()(const Arg &)`. For example, in the following case

```
struct foo {
  void operator(const int &) {}
};
```

I want `is_callable<foo, int &>` to be `false` and `is_callable<foo, const int &>` to be `true`. This is what I have so far :

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename F, typename Arg>
struct is_callable {
private:

  template<typename>
  static char (&test(...))[2];

  template<unsigned>
  struct helper {
    typedef void *type;
  };

  template<typename UVisitor>
  static char test(
               typename helper<
                 sizeof(std::declval<UVisitor>()(std::declval<Arg>()), 0)
                 >::type
               );
public:
  static const bool value = (sizeof(test<F>(0)) == sizeof(char));
};

struct foo {
  void operator()(const int &) {}
};

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  cout << is_callable<foo, int &>::value << "\n";
  cout << is_callable<foo, const int &>::value << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This prints `1` and `1`, but I want `0` and `1` because `foo` only defines `void operator()(const int &)`.

Comment: I have an idea using `is_constructible` along with a helper class which contains a member of type `decltype(F()(Arg()))`, but it's getting a bit more involved than my attention span permits just now. I think if this whole class were to be put into a SFINAE test, it might work.

Comment: I'm also interested in a solution to this problem, particularly one which would handle cases where ```foo::operator()``` is overloaded and/or a template.

Comment: `decltype(F()(Arg()))` will not work as expected, as Arg will be again converted from `const int` to `int`.

Comment: "I want is_callable<foo, int &> to be false and is_callable<foo, const int &> to be true." But won't that be a lie? You can pass a non-const reference to a function that takes a `const&`. Presumably, you want `is_callable` to be true if you can call the function with the given parameter, not if the function *takes* that parameter's value directly. Yes?

Comment: @Nicol: I agree that `is_callable` isn't the right name for such a trait, nevertheless, it's an interesting trait to design.

Comment: What should be the result when testing `struct foo {
  void operator(const int &, char arg2 = 0) {}
};`?

Comment: @Ben: [This version](http://ideone.com/iFY31) evaluates to `1` for the `Pling` case, however I have no idea how it does that, as it clearly shouldn't (there is no correct overload of `sfinae` available that takes a second argument, because after expanding the template parameters, it's `char sfinae(int (Pling::*)(char const&));`... any clue?).

Comment: @Xeo: And [here](http://ideone.com/xA76G) g++ knows it isn't a match.  Did you test that case with clang?  And how is Comeau tryitout coming with C++0x support, is there enough to test these (of course using `static_assert`, since execution isn't permitted)?

Comment: @Ben: Please come to the C++ chat room. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After hours of playing around and some [serious discussions in the C++ chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2392901#2392901), we finally got a version that works for functors with possibly overloaded or inherited `operator()` and for function pointers, based on @KerrekSB's and @BenVoigt's versions.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F, typename... Args>
class Callable{
  static int tester[1];
  typedef char yes;
  typedef yes (&no)[2];

  template <typename G, typename... Brgs, typename C>
  static typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<G,C>::value, char>::type
      sfinae(decltype(std::declval<G>()(std::declval<Brgs>()...)) (C::*pfn)(Brgs...));

  template <typename G, typename... Brgs, typename C>
  static typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<G,C>::value, char>::type
      sfinae(decltype(std::declval<G>()(std::declval<Brgs>()...)) (C::*pfn)(Brgs...) const);

  template <typename G, typename... Brgs>
  static char sfinae(decltype(std::declval<G>()(std::declval<Brgs>()...)) (G::*pfn)(Brgs...));

  template <typename G, typename... Brgs>
  static char sfinae(decltype(std::declval<G>()(std::declval<Brgs>()...)) (G::*pfn)(Brgs...) const);

  template <typename G, typename... Brgs>
  static yes test(int (&a)[sizeof(sfinae<G,Brgs...>(&G::operator()))]);

  template <typename G, typename... Brgs>
  static no test(...);

public:
  static bool const value = sizeof(test<F, Args...>(tester)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template<class R, class... Args>
struct Helper{ R operator()(Args...); };
 
template<typename R, typename... FArgs, typename... Args>
class Callable<R(*)(FArgs...), Args...>
  : public Callable<Helper<R, FArgs...>, Args...>{};
```

[Live example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/Q20BZ). Note that the two failing tests are overloaded `operator()` tests. This is a GCC bug with variadic templates, already fixed in GCC 4.7. Clang 3.1 also reports all tests as `passed`.

If you want `operator()` with default arguments to fail, there is a possible way to do that, however some other tests will start failing at that point and I found it as too much hassle to try and correct that.

**Edit:** As @Johannes correctly notes in the comment, we got a little inconsistency in here, namely that [functors which define a conversion to function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8873048/500104) will not be detected as "callable". This is, imho, pretty non-trivial to fix, as such I won't bother with it (for now). If you absolutely need this trait, well, leave a comment and I'll see what I can do.

---

Now that all this has been said, ***IMHO***, the idea for this trait is stupid. Why whould you have such *exact* requirements? Why would the standard `is_callable` not suffice?

(Yes, I think the idea is stupid. Yes, I still went and built this. Yes, it was fun, very much so. No, I'm not insane. Atleast that's what I believe...)

Comment: Function pointers do not have an operator() so they ahould report that they are not callable according to the question. Otherwise if you want to catch any callable type, you need to handle also class types that have a conversion function to function pointer or reference type.

Comment: @Johannes: The first part is rather easy, just let the partial spec of `Callable` have a `static bool const value = false;` member instead of inheriting from itself. The second part... is a good point that could get slightly complicated so I'm not gonna bother with it for now. :( This answer is also missing tests for `volatile` or ref-qualifed member functions, but those are *rather easy* to add, although it gets very messy in the number of `sfinae` overloads.

Comment: @Xeo : Quick question ... when are the three-template argument versions of `sfinae` instantiated?  I went to your example on ideone and commented out those template functions, and got the same results.

Comment: @Jason: That's interesting. Theoretically they're there for the `Inh` case, where the `operator()` is inherited, because in that case the class-type of the member function pointer differs from the class-type you want to test (`&Inh::operator()` is of type `int (Bar::*)(int const&)`). I got a FAILED there before I added those overloads that deduce the class-type on the pointer. Lemme recheck...

Comment: @Jason: Sheesh, found the error. It was a copy-paste problem with the last testcase. I may have written that `Inh` is going to be tested, but actually `Bar` got tested, that's why. I was seriously worried over my sanity. After replacing `test<Bar>` with `test<Inh>` in the last line [this is the outcome](http://ideone.com/E0LbU), which correctly reports `FAILED`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: What i dont understand, why not just do value(args) in an sfinae context. if "value" is callable, then no sfinae happens. why dont you take that trivial way but instead bother with taking addresses of members?

Comment: @Johannes: Read all the comments in this thread again. The OP specifically wanted to have a test with `operator()(int const&)` and a `int&` argument to report false. This is achieved with the roundabout way through member pointers.

Comment: @Jared: It correctly reports false on that w.r.t OP's specifications. Only the the `operator()` took a reference argument it would return `1`: http://ideone.com/lu9Lp

Answer (score 7):

(with apologies to Kerrek for using his answer as a starting point)

EDIT: Updated to handle types without any `operator()` at all.

```
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename Arg>
struct Callable
{
private:
  static int tester[1];
  typedef char                      yes;
  typedef struct { char array[2]; } no;

  template <typename G, typename Brg>
  static char sfinae(decltype(std::declval<G>()(std::declval<Brg>())) (G::*pfn)(Brg)) { return 0; }

  template <typename G, typename Brg>
  static char sfinae(decltype(std::declval<G>()(std::declval<Brg>())) (G::*pfn)(Brg) const) { return 0; }

  template <typename G, typename Brg>
  static yes test(int (&a)[sizeof(sfinae<G,Brg>(&G::operator()))]);

  template <typename G, typename Brg>
  static no test(...);

public:
  static bool const value = sizeof(test<F, Arg>(tester)) == sizeof(yes);
};

struct Foo
{
  int operator()(int &) { return 1; }

};

struct Bar
{
  int operator()(int const &) { return 2; }
};

struct Wazz
{
  int operator()(int const &) const { return 3; }
};

struct Frob
{
  int operator()(int &) { return 4; }
  int operator()(int const &) const { return 5; }
};

struct Blip
{
  template<typename T>
  int operator()(T) { return 6; }
};

struct Boom
{

};

struct Zap
{
  int operator()(int) { return 42; }
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Foo(const int &):  " << Callable<Foo,  int const &>::value << std::endl
            << "Foo(int &):        " << Callable<Foo,  int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Bar(const int &):  " << Callable<Bar,  const int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Bar(int &):        " << Callable<Bar,  int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Zap(const int &):  " << Callable<Zap , const int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Zap(int&):         " << Callable<Zap , int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Wazz(const int &): " << Callable<Wazz, const int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Wazz(int &):       " << Callable<Wazz, int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Frob(const int &): " << Callable<Frob, const int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Frob(int &):       " << Callable<Frob, int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Blip(const int &): " << Callable<Blip, const int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Blip(int &):       " << Callable<Blip, int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Boom(const int &): " << Callable<Boom, const int &>::value << std::endl
            << "Boom(int&):        " << Callable<Boom, int &>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/T3Iry

Comment: It, interestingly, also works for a `operator()(int)`: http://ideone.com/egvJl. Well done, +1. :)

Comment: I have an idea how to fix that, gimme a sec.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That is one area where the original poster's design works well ... if the `operator()` doesn't exist at all, it fails gracefully and gives a false value.

Comment: @Xeo: All better now... maybe.

Comment: @Ben: Aww, I just finished [my version](http://ideone.com/9Ok2C) too. :( Yours looks a lot cleaner though.

Comment: That's cool, yours also does fine in [the overloaded case](http://ideone.com/pczhr). I don't understand how, though, since there is still no contextual information of which overload to choose.

Comment: @Xeo: What I'm worried about are the ordinary functions.  Algorithms are supposed to allow you to pass a functor OR ordinary function pointer, and which operator `()` can be applied to a function pointer, I'm pretty sure the pointer-to-member syntax can't.

Comment: @Xeo: In the overloaded case, there's failure.  But SFINAE, so all's good.

Comment: @Ben: There is no failure, since we correctly get a `1` for `Callable<Boom, const int &>::value`. I think it's because there is no `sfinae(...);` version, so there actually *is* contextual information of which overload to choose, after template parameter substitution. Nice.

Comment: It's interesting to note that GCC 4.5.1 reports `0` for the overloaded cases when using [variadic templates](http://ideone.com/H1qLX). Testing with Clang 3.1 however confirms that everything is indeed OK, reporting `1` for the overloaded cases. FWIW, I got a version together that [works with function pointers](http://ideone.com/63g8S). Note the problem with overloads in the variadic version here. It works correctly with Clang 3.1.

Comment: @Xeo: You should make that an answer, it's much more powerful than mine.

Comment: @BenVoigt: okay, you and Xeo are both nuts! Great demo!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe? It's a bit round about to make it work on VS2010.

```
template<typename FPtr>
struct function_traits_impl;

template<typename R, typename A1>
struct function_traits_impl<R (*)(A1)>
{
    typedef A1 arg1_type;
};

template<typename R, typename C, typename A1>
struct function_traits_impl<R (C::*)(A1)>
{
    typedef A1 arg1_type;
};

template<typename R, typename C, typename A1>
struct function_traits_impl<R (C::*)(A1) const>
{
    typedef A1 arg1_type;
};

template<typename T>
typename function_traits_impl<T>::arg1_type arg1_type_helper(T);

template<typename F>
struct function_traits
{
    typedef decltype(arg1_type_helper(&F::operator())) arg1_type;
};

template<typename F, typename Arg>
struct is_callable : public std::is_same<typename function_traits<F>::arg1_type, const Arg&>
{
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the class has more than one `operator()` overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I hacked up which may or may not be what you need; it does seem to give true (false) for `(const) int &`...

```
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename Arg>
struct Callable
{
private:
  typedef char                      yes;
  typedef struct { char array[2]; } no;

  template <typename G, typename Brg>
  static yes test(decltype(std::declval<G>()(std::declval<Brg>())) *);

  template <typename G, typename Brg>
  static no test(...);

public:
  static bool const value = sizeof(test<F, Arg>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
};

struct Foo
{
  int operator()(int &) { return 1; }
  // int operator()(int const &) const { return 2; } // enable and compare
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Foo(const int &): " << Callable<Foo, int const &>::value << std::endl
            << "Foo(int &):       " << Callable<Foo, int &>::value << std::endl
    ;
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. The problem is, if Foo looks like this,`struct Foo
{
  int operator()(const int &) const { return 2; } 
};`, then `Callable<Foo, int &>::value` is 1. I expected 0.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution that utilizes an extra test to see if your template is being instantiated with a `const T&`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename F, typename Arg>
struct is_callable {
private:

  template<typename>
  static char (&test(...))[2];

  template<bool, unsigned value>
  struct helper {};

  template<unsigned value>
  struct helper<true, value> {
    typedef void *type;
  };

  template<typename T>
  struct is_const_ref {};

  template<typename T>
  struct is_const_ref<T&> {
    static const bool value = false;
  };

  template<typename T>
  struct is_const_ref<const T&> {
    static const bool value = true;
  };

  template<typename UVisitor>
  static char test(typename helper<is_const_ref<Arg>::value, 
                                   sizeof(std::declval<UVisitor>()(std::declval<Arg>()), 0)>::type);
public:
  static const bool value = (sizeof(test<F>(0)) == sizeof(char));
};

struct foo {
  void operator()(const int &) {}
};

int main(void)
{
  cout << is_callable<foo, int &>::value << "\n";
  cout << is_callable<foo, const int &>::value << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But then you'll need a special case for `volatile`.  And one for `volatile const`.

Comment: It depends on the `operator()` declaration in the passed-in functor, I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this while doing something else, was able to adapt my code to fit.  It has the same features (and limitations) as @Xeo, but does not need sizeof trick/enable_if.  The default parameter takes the place of needing to do the enable_if to handle template functions.  I tested it under g++ 4.7 and clang 3.2 using the same test code Xeo wrote up

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

namespace detail {
  template<typename T, class Args, class Enable=void>
  struct call_exact : std::false_type {};

  template<class...Args> struct ARGS { typedef void type; };

  template<class T, class ... Args, class C=T>
  C * opclass(decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<Args>()...)) (C::*)(Args...)) { }
  template<class T, class ... Args, class C=T>
  C * opclass(decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<Args>()...)) (C::*)(Args...) const) { }

  template<typename T, class ... Args>
  struct call_exact<T, ARGS<Args...>,
    typename ARGS<
       decltype(std::declval<T&>()(std::declval<Args>()...)),
       decltype(opclass<T, Args...>(&T::operator()))
     >::type
   > : std::true_type {};
}

template<class T, class ... Args>
struct Callable : detail::call_exact<T, detail::ARGS<Args...>> { };

template<typename R, typename... FArgs, typename... Args>
struct Callable<R(*)(FArgs...), Args...>
 : Callable<std::function<R(FArgs...)>, Args...>{};
```